# React - require('net') returns empty object

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I need to check in React app if given server is reachable using node **"net"** module.

But something like this returns me empty Object:

```
const net = require('net');
console.log(net);
```

[image: logs]

Does someone know what might cause it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is built in node module available on a server. You can't use it directly in your client code so it is replaced by webpack. Assuming you are using CRA https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L749

Comment: If my webpack is also garbbed from node_modules from "start kit", what can I do?